# Client/Server configuration issue with a Service Reference

Tags: c#, configuration, service-reference

I am running a Client/Server WinForm application.

I added a Service Reference to a server side project.

However during runtime I get the following error:

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract '' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

However the  node does exist.  Is there a certain section that it needs to reside in?  Could I have it located in the wrong location of the web.config file?

Currently in my web.config it is in the

```
"<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
     my endpoint node
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>"
```

Comment: please can you show us the serviceModel config from your web.config

Comment: <system.serviceModel><bindings><basicHttpBinding><binding> This node craeted when I added SVC Reference.
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<client>
<endpoint address="https://services.relayhealth.com/AtsWebServices/pub/Batch"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BatchFilesBinding"
    contract="wsRelayClaimStats.BatchFiles" name="BatchFilesPort" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>

Comment: please check and let me know if you have the behavior called "BatchFilesBinding" in <behaviours><serviceBehaviors><behavior name="BatchFilesBinding">......

Comment: There is no reference of "behaviours" in either my web.config or app.config file.

Comment: you will need to add behaviour called BatchFilesBinding here is an e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee358768.aspx

Comment: You mention "BatchFilesBinding" but I see nothing mentioned in the msdn link for that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

please check your contract in endpoint on client side, as your dnt provide the endpoint xml part of config file we cant tell what is the issue. but what i think contract part of endpoint is making an issue

Comment: I have the same endpointnode in the app.config file on the client.

Comment: put client name space infront of the rest which is mention in the contact as contract="clientnamespace.rest..."